# How to get index based on value in pyspark list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list like below

```
[[[Row(cola=53273831, colb=1197), Row(cola=15245438, colb=1198)], [Row(cola=53273831, colb=1198)]]]
```

Here I want to search for a particular element and get the index value of it. Ex:

```
mylist.index((([['53273831', '1198']])))
```

should give me index as 1. But I'm getting error

```
ValueError: [['53273831', '1198']] is not in list.
```

This the code I'm using

```
df2=df.groupBy("order").agg(collect_list(struct(["id","node_id"])).alias("res"))
newrdd = df2.rdd.map(lambda x : (x))
order_info = newrdd.collectAsMap()
dict_values=(list(order_info.values()))
dict_keys=(list(order_info.keys()))
a=[[53273831, 1198]]
k2= dict_keys[dict_values.index(((a)))]  # This line is givin
```

g me the error :ValueError: [['53273831', '1198']] is not in list

order_info dict looks like this
{10160700: [Row(id=53273831, node_id=1197), Row(id=15245438, node_id=1198)], 101600201: [Row(iid=53273831, node_id=1198)]}

Can you please help me to get the index value from this struct type list?

Comment: please post the code you are using that gives you the error

Comment: df2=df.groupBy("order").agg(collect_list(struct(["id","node_id"])).alias("res"))
newrdd = df2.rdd.map(lambda x : (x))
order_info = newrdd.collectAsMap()
dict_values=(list(order_info.values()))
dict_keys=(list(order_info.keys()))
a=[[53273831, 1198]]
k2= dict_keys[dict_values.index(((a)))]  # This line is giving me the error :ValueError: [['53273831', '1198']] is not in list

order_info dict looks like this 
{10160700: [Row(id=53273831, node_id=1197), Row(id=15245438, node_id=1198)], 101600201: [Row(iid=53273831, node_id=1198)]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is a Row object, not a list, so you need to specify the Row object. Also you should get the index from mylist[0] because mylist is a multilayer array.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

mylist = [[[Row(cola=53273831, colb=1197), Row(cola=15245438, colb=1198)], [Row(cola=53273831, colb=1198)]]]

id = mylist[0].index([Row(cola=53273831, colb=1198)])
```

will give you an id of 1.